# Missed Meggilah at Night make up by day

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, mistakes

If someone missed Meggilah at night, does he do it twice by day?

Comment: Why do you think he might? What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be made up 
[Source- question number 6](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/02/06/purim-the-megilah/)